# Help designing a Table(s) with a single message to multiple placeholder values, with new placeholders added occasionally

Tags: mysql, relational-theory

The basic situation is I have a single 'message' table, and currently our design for this is a single row, with all placeholde values stored against the row at generation, so they are available for editing of the message itself.

My issue is, we are constantly adding placeholders, not often but enough, where we have around 30 currently, and this specific table has now grown to 30mil rows. It seems to be getting slower when processing, and each time we add a placeholder it takes half an hour currently, and this is only going to get longer as the number of rows increase, which is happening rapidly.

Is this the best way to handle the placeholder values, most of which are NOT set, or is there a better way of having that relationship, and speeding up how we handle our data?

I have researched EAV (message_id | placeholder_id | placeholder_value) in addition to another 'placeholder' table, but this seems to be bad practice from what I have read.

We are considering archiving data at this point, but if there is a better way to handle the DB structure, I would like to implement it.

Thankyou for any help!

Comment: Please add a [mcve] showing the current table design along with sample data.  As it is, it's hard to tell what you mean by "placeholder".  Please [edit] your question with the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [Normalization](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html) and possibly implementing [Star Schema](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.guru99.com/star-snowflake-data-warehousing.html&ved=2ahUKEwjHioPPlr3tAhVbWs0KHTItCrEQFjAhegQIIRAB&usg=AOvVaw06yHNJTuJoFdu3qeeqfSvi).

These are design techniques used to appropriately divide your Table structure into a more efficient schema both from a query processing and data redundancy standpoint.

The 5 second version being, can you break up your Message table such that a lot of the placeholder fields go into their own separate Table(s)? If so, it should help with querying when you SELECT only the fields you need and when you need to add more placeholder fields, they can potentially be added to a less wide table if it's not on the Message table.

It's also helpful from a concurrency contention standpoint too if you need update one field that's in one of the placeholder Tables, concurrently to the Message table being read from as it won't cause write locks on the Message table.

Comment: Ok, so looking at that normalization 3, I would then only need to create a new table each time we add a placeholder, which would take no time at all, and then the ONLY time we actually would access this info is if the placeholder is within the message itself, at which point we can dynamically build the query to only join on those tags. I would say this would be fast for multiple selects as well (batches of 2000), unless you disagree?

Comment: Yes 3NF would probably be helpful for your case. If they are a group of strongly related fields they could probably go into the same Table otherwise they can be divided as appropriately to their own tables. Then new placeholder fields can be either added to the existing Tables you've normalized already or if unrelated can get their own Table. And then yes, depending on your querying needs, you can either dynamically build the query or pre-define them ahead of time. (Sorry if my answers are a little generic, but if you provide more context I probably can give more specific information.)